# how to set different urls.py file bases on user in django

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-middleware

I have two urls file in my base project:
urls.py
admin_urls.py

depending on the requested user, different urls will be accessed. And users are differentiated based on the request.
I created a middleware file which contains:

```
class URLHandlerMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        # if not request.user.is_anonymous:
        if not request.user.user:
            if request.META['saleschannel'] == SALES_CHANNEL_IDS['a510b9']:
                request.urlconf = 'hyp_users_svc.admin_urls'
            else:
                request.urlconf = 'hyp_users_svc.urls'
        return response
```

users are differentaiated based on this parameter saleschannel.

This is my middlewares list in settings

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'oauth2_provider.middleware.OAuth2TokenMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'hyp_users_svc.services.versioned.v1.middlewares.url_handler.URLHandlerMiddleware',  ## my url middleware
    'hyp_users_svc.services.versioned.v1.middlewares.error_handler.ErrorResponseMiddleware'
]
```

But this is not working.
There might be a problem with ordering of middleware, but i tried to call my middleware initially but still its not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you should try django redirects https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/redirects/ instead of handling this with a custom middleware.

Comment: that would not work in my case as I dont want to redirect the user. I just want to give 404 if that url does not exist for that user

Answer (score 0):

did you add the authentication backend? Adding authentication might solve the issue

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'oauth2_provider.backends.OAuth2Backend',
    # Uncomment following if you want to access the admin
    #'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
    '...',
)
```

work?

Comment: yes i have authentication backend added already:
```AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'oauth2_provider.backends.OAuth2Backend',
    # Uncomment following if you want to access the admin
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
]```

Answer (score 0):

Authentication and authorization are two different concepts. What you are looking for is authorisation based on a user role.
A custom login decorator which takes that into account and redirect the user based on its role should do it.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem with the current codebase was that it was using the **call** method which returns the response of the request. Instead i had to update my process_request method which will simply process the code befoe the request.

```
class URLHandlerMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        # for unprotected calls
        if 'saleschannel' in request.headers:
            if request.headers['saleschannel'] == 'a510b9':
                set_urlconf('hyp_users_svc.admin_urls')
                request.urlconf = 'hyp_users_svc.admin_urls'

            else:
                request.urlconf = 'hyp_users_svc.urls'
        return None
```

using the MiddlewareMixin will automatically call my **init** and **call** method. I just had to decide the url file to be used which is done in process_request method.
The only issue with this approcah is that I am not able to access request.META with this request param. so i had to write some additional code